# Mod Rewrite L Flag Not stopping

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why does:

```
http://example.com/robots.txt
```

redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/mvc/view/robots/live-robots.txt
```

with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^robots.txt /mvc/view/robots/live-robots.txt [L]
#.... 20 irrelevant lines for mobile rewrites
# Force the "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

loading this however:

```
http://www.example.com/robots.txt
```

rewrites the `live-robots.txt` as expected.

Shouldn't the `L` flag stop the redirect in both cases and not get to the latter rule?

> The L flag can be useful in this context to end the current round of mod_rewrite processing.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Current execution paths:

1. http://example.com/robots.txt
2. 301 served
3. http://www.example.com/mvc/view/robots/live-robots.txt

and then

1. http://www.example.com/robots.txt
2. 200 (contents of mvc/view/robots/live-robots.txt are served)

I'm pretty sure it isn't a regex issue but here's testing of that too, https://regex101.com/r/eI9aC4/1.

Comment: What do your rewrite logs look like?

Comment: From the access logs or are there re-write specific logs somewhere? Access logs have `80 GET /robots.txt  301` then  
`80 GET /mvc/view/robots/live-robots.txt  304`.

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) (or [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for Apache 2.2).

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com` (after [OR] of course a linebreak)

Comment: @larsks thanks for that link. That was useful, had to be in `httpd.conf`, not `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag `L` doesn't stop other rules to execute. It just acts as `continue` in a `while` loop and makes `mod_rewrite` loop to run again.

Your rules need to be reversed in order. In general keep redirect rules before internal rewrite ones:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force the "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ mvc/view/robots/live-robots.txt [L,NC]
#.... 20 irrelevant lines for mobile rewrites
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache for this change.

However if you have Apache 2.4+ then you can use `END` flag to completely stop all the rules below:

```
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ mvc/view/robots/live-robots.txt [END]
```

Comment: I'm running 2.2.15 so `end` is not available to me. There's no way in 2.2 to explicitly have the file stop processing?

Comment: No `END` was added from Apache 2.4+ onwards. For `2.2` you should keep redirect rules before rewrite rules as I suggested.

Comment: Thanks, that answers this question. On to looking into upgrading to 2.4.