# Apache2 mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2.4

Setting up rewriting directly to virtual host as

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        # handles landing page
        RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]

        RewriteRule ^(.+)$ post.php?clean_url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

accessing the website `http://192.168.1.120` leads to URL `http://192.168.1.120/post.php?clean_url="index.php"`, which does not exist.

It seems that the first rule rewrites `http://192.168.1.120` to  `http://192.168.1.120/index.php` , but **it does not stop there**; the second rule, in turn, leads to  `http://192.168.1.120/post.php?clean_url="index.php`. Why the second rule is involve here? I expect the first rewriting rule to be the `L`ast in this case. Am I missing some rewriting concepts?

My apache version is

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2022-06-14T12:30:21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36293353/4381271), reversing the order of those two rules fixed the problem